# How to re-fetch single items of a collection in react-query

Tags: reactjs, normalization, react-query

Let's say i have a query to fetch a collection of movies:

```
useQuery(['movies'], getMovies)
```

Now, if I want to re-fetch only one movie instead of all I can write something like this:

```
useQuery(['movies', movieId], () => getMovie(movieId))
```

Problem is that I use a different query key and that it will duplicate the data. I'll have the movie in my cache twice.

So, what's the react-query way of updating a single item of a fetched collection? All components that use `useQuery(['movies'])` should be updated automatically when the single item was fetched.

Comment: Does the following link answer your question? https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/474
You can load the single item from the backend, and then update the cache as in the above link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are two ways:

1. like you described with a new key. yes, the data will be "twice" in the cache, but oftentimes, the "list" data has a different structure than the "detail" data. movies-list might just have id and name, while the details have a description etc. as well. If you do that, make sure to give them both the same prefix (`'movies'`), so that you can utilize the fuzzy matching when invalidating: `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['movies'])` will then invalidate the list and all details, which is nice.
2. you can use the select option to build a detail query on:

```
const useMovies = (select) => useQuery(['movies'], getMovies, { select })
const useMovie = (id) => useMovies(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.id === id))
```

with that, you can do `useMovie(5)` and thus will only subscribe to the movie with id 5. This is really nice and also render optimized - if the movie with id 4 updates, the component that subscribes to movie with id 5 will *not* re-render.

the "drawback" is of course that for the data / network perspective, there is only one query - the list query, so everytime you do background refetches, the whole list will be queried from the backend. But it's still a nice approach to avoid data duplication in the cache, and it makes optimistic updates easier as well, because you only have to write to update one cache entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case both solutions are not ideal. (1) is suboptimal because of the reason you already mentioned (data duplication), In this case data fetched by the list and detail calls are equal in terms of their structure. (2) is not sufficient as well because i need to re-fetch the data. I want to do that for only one movie without reloading all movies.

Comment: I'm afraid react-query doesn't have a normalized cache, you can see that as the only red bullet point in the comparison: http://react-query.tanstack.com/comparison

There is some work being done to support that in the future, but it needs an underlying schema that just doesn't exist yet.